# Varnish symfony esi: tag remove, but no content

Tags: symfony, varnish, esi

So my problem: I have a big symfony project 2.3, varnish 5. So I want to include some fragment by symfony function render_esi(). After all problem I want to understand why doesn't include any file, even simply test.php. The problem is it's not include any content, but tag esi:include src"..."
I don't see. 
Ok, let's see all configs:

Symfony:
config.yml

```
esi: 
    enabled: true
fragments:
    path: /_fragments
```

some.html.twig:

```
<h2>Here must be content</h2>

{{ render_esi(url('esi_megamenuBanners')) }}
{{ render_esi(controller("OstrovWebBundle:Frontend/Page:megamenuBanners")) }}
<esi:include src="https://mo.loc/test.php">

<h2>end content</h2>
```

Its a three different ways, which I tried to fire ESI.

Varnish config:

```
sub vcl_recv {

#Add a Surrogate-Capability header to announce ESI support.
set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";

}


sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}
```

I checked the both headers *Surrogate-Control* and *Surrogate-Capability* - they exists.

By the way, I use nginx:https -> varnish -> nginx:http:8080 -> symfony project.

I spend much time for experiments and I didn't find any decision... Please tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: In your app.php file, are you using AppCache? If so try disabling it.

Comment: No, I don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that is an answer: **ESI does not work with https**! I just write *path()* function instead *url()* and everything became all right!

(I didn't find any information about https and ESI, maybe I wrong; so be carefull...)

Second I've not understood that *Surrogate-Control* need not for ESI sub-requests, so I was in delusion when configure my cache rules. *Surrogate-Control* **don't use in sub-requests**.

The third thing which I grasped is different between *render_esi(url("someUrl"))* and *render_esi(controller("someBundle:nameOfController:someAction"))*: first make url which you point before in routing; second use [fragments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/esi.html#using-esi-in-symfony). So it would be helpful for cache rules.